# Does Autodesk Eagle 9.XX support project files sync like Fusion 360?

Tags: eaglecad

I am using Eagle 9.0.1 and I have been searching about syncing project files and accessing my projects files from multiple places but I could not really find such a thing anywhere in the software and it is not happening automatically.

I am asking this question because when you open the program in the main window, you have this "GO ONLINE" so I thought it is the same as Fusion360.

My question: **Does Autodesk Eagle 9.XX support project files syncing(similar to Fusion360)?**

Comment: Have you considered using some sort of version-control repository? I personally use github for my projects, but I've seen some demos in CADLAB.io that look great.

Comment: Well, I am familiar with a version-control repository since I am a software engineer, so "Github" definitely would be the ideal solution, but when I saw "Go online"(I came from Eagle 7.6) I thought it will be like Fusion360 for managing projects files!